Intercept squid in microk8s
0
I want to create a highly available default gateway with Squid(intercept witch ssl) and Redsocks. Squid performs some domain-based load balancing, forwarding specific domains to Redsocks, and the rest to the standard gateway. I am using ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with microk8s(1.31.3) in my network, deployed on 3 nodes. For IP address distribution in the network, I use MetalLB. The problem is that I don't know how to forward ALL ports of svc to the pods. This can only be done one port at a time, like this example:
ports: protocol:  TCP port: 80  targetPort: 80
I can also use NodePort with iptables on each node. However, in this case, I need an external load balancer, which I currently don't have.
There are no ranges. I think if I specify about 65,000 ports, my MetalLB load balancer will become extremely slow. What is the best way to handle this situation?

why are you asking here?

@graham microk8s this is a development from snap, which belongs to ubuntu. Also, all the documentation about microk8s is on the ubuntu websites.

which version/flavour of Ubuntu are you using. [edit] your question accordingly
